# Can I share a SCSI device with another machine over the network?

Tags: linux, devices

I have a SCSI Controller which is connected to a Tape changer/LTO Drive:

```
# lsscsi  
[12:0:2:0]   tape    HP       Ultrium 4-SCSI   W61U  /dev/st0   
[12:0:2:1]   mediumx TANDBERG StorageLoader    0495  /dev/sch0
```

I also have a VM on that machine which is running the backup software.

As the SCSI Controller is on the Host, the VM can't directly access it. I'm aware of PCI Passthrough, but this won't work because I can't put the SCSI Controller in its own IOMMU group.

I could install client software on the Host to access the drive, but I would prefer to keep all relevant software on that VM.

So I wonder, is there a way to share an entire SCSI device (in this case, /dev/st0 and /dev/sch0) with another Linux host? So I can access /dev/something on the VM just like I would access it on the Host, and have it transparently "forward" data back and forth.

Both machines run Linux, the Host is Proxmox VE (based on Debian 10.3), the VM is Ubuntu 18.04 (though I could install Debian instead).

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Using iSCSI to share Discs and Tape](https://linuxfestnorthwest.org/conferences/2019/program/proposals/231)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thank you, mind posting that as an answer so I can upvote it? iSCSI seems to be the solution for this, I'll try it out on Linux.

Comment: I don't want to write what's essentially a link-only answer. If it turns out to work for you, could you post the steps you took? That would be better than any summary I could write.